# R collapse column to form numeric list

Tags: r

In `R` hoe do I collapse column to form another column with numeric lists types.

like we define numeric  list as  `l = c(1,2,3)`

```
df <- read.table(text = "X  Y
a   26
a   3
a   24
b   8
b   1
b   4
", header = TRUE)
```

I am trying this with `dplyr` but it gives me character list column

```
> df %>% group_by(X) %>% summarise(lst= paste0(Y, collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  X     lst    
  <fct> <chr>  
1 a     26,3,24
2 b     8,1,4
```

Answer (score 2):

group by `X` then summarise `Y` as `list`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
  group_by(X) %>% 
  summarise(Y = list(Y))
out
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  X     Y        
#  <fct> <list>   
#1 a     <int [3]>
#2 b     <int [3]>
```

The `Y` column now looks like this

```
out$Y
#[[1]]
#[1] 26  3 24
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 8 1 4
```

---

`nest` seems to be another option but this would result in a list column of `tibbles` (not what you want I think)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(X) %>% 
  nest()
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  X     data            
#  <fct> <list>          
#1 a     <tibble [3 × 1]>
#2 b     <tibble [3 × 1]>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)[, list(Y=list(Y)), by="X"]
```

---

```
> dt
   X        Y
1: a 26, 3,24
2: b    8,1,4
> dt$Y
[[1]]
[1] 26  3 24

[[2]]
[1] 8 1 4
```